# iOS indexOfObjectIdenticalTo: not working for strings

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray

I've seen similar questions about NSArray's `indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:` method, but I'm hoping my asking it simply will yield simple answers.  Is it useless for searching for strings that are programmatically built?

```
NSArray* theArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"John", nil];
NSString* searchString1 = @"John";
NSString* stringComponent = @"Jo";
NSString* searchString2 = [stringComponent stringByAppendingFormat:@"hn"];

BOOL testContains1 = [theArray containsObject:searchString1];
int  testIndex1    = [theArray indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:searchString1];
BOOL testContains2 = [theArray containsObject:searchString2];
int  testIndex2    = [theArray indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:searchString2];
```

In the example above, `testContains1` and `testContains2` both return the same value, which is `true`.  But `testIndex1` and `testIndex2` differ; `testIndex1` is 0 because it found an identical object at index 0 as expected, but unfortunately `testIndex2` is 2147483647 (NSNotFound).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation about `indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:` says:

> Objects are considered identical if their object addresses are the same.

This will obviously not be the case for objects that have the same content, but are constructed differently.

You need to use `indexOfObject:` in this case, which will give you the lowest index of an object that returns `YES` from the `isEqual:` method.

Comment: Thanks!  I confused the two methods, thinking that `indexOfObject:` looked for matching object addresses, but I should've read the documentation more carefully.